# RoundRobin algorithm with queue

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a question about roundrobin algorithm with queue and I am new with data structures. The algorithm should make this:

- we get 3 numbers like `(12 5 8)`  and one quantum number for example `q:10`
- Then algorithm should make this :

  ```
  step1: 12 5 18
  step2: 5 18 2
  step3: 18 2
  step4: 2 8
  step5: 8
  step6: array is empty
  ```

As you see when quantum number is equal or bigger than array's number, we will delete first number in array. when quantum number is smaller than our number ,then quantum-number `(12-10=2)` will  be added to the end of the array.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Please refer this [How To Ask Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , Good question asked get up voted easily, voted question get more attraction to get good answer.

Comment: god bless your example which is clearer than your problem statement

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You want to:

- store the list in an `ArrayList` (or something similar)
- get the first item
- check whether or not it is larger than `quantum`
- If so, add it to the back of the list (after subtracting `quantum` of
  course).

Just continue until the ArrayList is empty.

***Here is the code:***

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(12);
values.add(5);
values.add(18);
int quantum = 10;
int index = 0;
while (values.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(values.toString());
    int value = values.remove(0);
    if (value > quantum) {
        values.add(value - quantum);
    }
}
System.out.println("Array is empty");
```

***This will give you the desired result:***

```
[12, 5, 18]
[5, 18, 2]
[18, 2]
[2, 8]
[8]
Array is empty
```